# Users able to approve their own records when not assigned as approver

Tags: approval-process

I have created an approval process on one of the custom object.

I have three users named as User 1, User 2, User 3

Upon Clicking on the Submit for approval button, the fields in the approval history is being updated as below.

Assigned to - User 1 Actual Approver - User 1

But when i have logged in as User 3 and im able to see the Approve button on the record and is able to approve the record. Then the approval history changes to as below

Assigned to(Second Step) - User 2    Actual Approver - User 2
Assigned to(First Step)  - User 1    Actual Approver - User 3

And yet again im able to update the record logging in as User 3 which should not happen in real time scenario.

I have verified the permissions given for the user 3. He doesn't have 'Modify All Data' permission and also doesn't have 'Modify All' permission as well.

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a note of following points to understand this behavior:

- Users with the following permissions can respond to approval requests, even if they aren’t designated approvers.

> “Modify All Data”
>
> “Modify All” for an object

- Make sure that the assigned approver has access to read the records for the approval requests. For example, a user who can’t view expense records can’t view expense approval requests.
- Approval processes that let users select an approver manually also
  let users select themselves as the approver.
- You can assign an approval request to the same user multiple times in
  a single step. However, Salesforce sends the user only one request.
- Here’s what happens to the list of approvers after a record enters an
  approval step and the approval process later returns to that step:

> If the user who responded isn’t in the designated approvers list and
> has either “Modify All Data” or “Modify All” permissions for the
> object, that user replaces the original approver in the list of
> approvers.
>
> If a user who responded is in the designated approvers list, the list
> of approvers for that step don’t change. This behavior occurs even if
> the field values that designate the approvers have changed.

This can also be found in [Considerations for Setting Approvers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.approvals_considerations_approver.htm&type=5)